# Dropzone JS - Destroy and recreate for same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using a form with dropzone in modal and I have a problem:
when the user opens the modal for the first time, I can create it fine, calling a new Dropzone("#my-form-id"). The problem is, when the user closes the modal and reopen it, I have to attach dropzone to the form again, 'cause it's rendered via ajax. As Dropzone was already attached, it gives me the error. I tried to destroy the my dropzone on closing modal and attach it again when the window reopen. It stops giving the error, but on that second time, it doesn't work. How can I attach dropzone multiple times for a same form (same id) in that situation? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some code? How are you destroying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about validate if the instance is already declared.
When I have already declared the dropXML in my case I avoid to declare again with this method.

```
if (Dropzone.instances.length == 0) {
    dropXML = new Dropzone("div#dropXML", dropXMLOptions);

    $('div.dropzone').find('div.dz-message').toggle();
    $('div.dropzone').find('div.dz-message').show();
}
```

Comment: OP said "'I have to attach dropzone to the form again, 'cause it's rendered via ajax." so I guess this is not the answer.

Comment: OK, how about save the options in a variable and later call this options to recreate it again. So you just destroy your dropzone with "X" options saved and later you create new dropzone in specified location with that options. It works for me.

Comment: I have found this. I hope it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/tomas_eklund/761qr3r5/39/